# Laravel Regular Expression Constants allowing invalid parameters

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes

I'm using Laravel 5.6

I have the following route that I want to allow only numeric values to be passed to `id`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.jwt']], function () {
    Route::get('endpoint/{id}/something', 'API\MyController@myMethod')
        ->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
});
```

- Method assignature: `public function myMethod($id)`

But even when I pass a *non-numeric* value to `id`, it's passing to `MyController` `@myMethod`, it's NOT preventing from executing the route.

Tried via the `RouterServiceProvider.php`, without success too:

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
    parent::boot();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please post the signature of the controller method MyController@myMethod

Comment: Do you have any other similar routes that might be matching it?

Comment: try changing it to `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: you surely have other routes conflicting, I have just tried your code and gives 404 on a alpha id. Try to run `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @dparoli Updated the question. How can I identify the conflicting routes?

Comment: @Matt.G Tried, no change

Comment: run the command `php artisan route:list` it gives you the list of routes declared in your app. So you can tell if some routes are conflicting.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know to prevent the user from entering a non-decimal value, but if i want to achieve the same result i will check first thing in `myMethod()` for the `$id` if isn't a decimal i will `abort(404)` or redirect user back with some message.